# .getContext() / this produces null object reference inside PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, null, sharedpreferences

I am making an app in which there is a login AlertDialog, this lets you choose you location.
But, when you change the location in the settings you of course need to relog using different credentials.
I used an onPreferenceClick for this.
But, whenever i try to open the settings i get this:

```
Process: nl.knapper_development.www.jrw, PID: 9068
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{nl.knapper_development.www.jrw/nl.knapper_development.www.jrw.instelling}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:131)
            at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:374)
            at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:369)
            at nl.knapper_development.www.jrw.instelling.<init>(instelling.java:114)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

This is my code:

```
public class instelling extends PreferenceActivity{

    final String loginScreenShownPref = "loginScreenShown";
    private static final boolean ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS = true;


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setupSimplePreferencesScreen();
    }

    private void setupSimplePreferencesScreen() {
        if (!isSimplePreferences(this)) {
            return;
        }

        //Voegd prefrences toe
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_locatie);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_thema);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_informatie);

        // Parsed de website
        Preference website = findPreference("website_knop");
        website.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://knapper-development.nl")));
                return true;
            }
        });

        // Versie Toast
        Preference versie = findPreference("versie_knop");
        versie.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

                String version = "";
                try {
                    version = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Toast.makeText(instelling.this, version, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
        return isXLargeTablet(this) && !isSimplePreferences(this);
    }

    private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
    }

    private static boolean isSimplePreferences(Context context) {
        return ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS
                || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB
                || !isXLargeTablet(context);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class InformatiePreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_informatie);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class ThemaPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_thema);
        }
    }

    SharedPreferences MainPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Preference filiaal = this.findPreference("filiaal_lijst");
        filiaal.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

                SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = MainPrefs.edit();
                prefEditor.putBoolean(loginScreenShownPref, false);
                prefEditor.apply();
                return true;

            }
        });

    }
}
```

When i run the debugger it tells me that `savedInstanceState = null`
Line 114 is `SharedPreferences MainPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);`
Without calling this i of course cannot update my preference, the preference i am updating is set to true when the login dialog is completed, and set to false when the "Change Location" preference is clicked.

I don't know why this is wrong, it seems to work for `Preference versie` and `Preference website`

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:

[image]

now the line: `filiaal.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {` seem to be the problem, is there a way to check why this is null?

Comment: It needs to be inside of a method

Comment: @codeMagic, orb an answer with a small explanation, would be nice

Comment: @Blackbelt bor, I agree but looking for a dupe because I've given this answer before

Comment: @Blackbelt Found one. How is that orb?

Comment: He is Partially right, this fixed my initial problem, but now i seem to have stumbled upon a completely new one...

Comment: That's a completely separate issue but maybe you need to add `addPreferencesFromResource(()`. I've never used it but that would be my guess. Or the other [add method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#addPreferencesFromIntent(android.content.Intent))

Comment: @codeMagic Also fixed it, i put the addpreferences before Preference filiaal and made that final, this has solved it for me and now works perfectly!

if you would be so kind to post the things you said as an answer, then i can mark it as the solution :)

Thanks a lot, i have been looking for a solution to this for 3 straight days...